# How do I cast from a heterogeneous array in Swift 4?

Tags: swift4

```
let data = ["1", "2", 3, 4, 5];

var m: Int = data[3] as! Int;
```

> error: MyPlayground.playground:238:12: error: heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional
>      let data = ["1", "2", 3, 4, 5];
>                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               as [Any]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try doing what the error suggests?

```
let data: [Any] = ["1", "2", 3, 4, 5]; // Added explicit type annotation
var m: Int = data[3] as! Int;
```